# mysql query problem

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

```
id   url                    start        end
1    http://yahoo.com      2010-10-17    2010-10-10
2    http://google.com     2010-10-15    2010-12-11
3    http://espan.com      2010-10-20    2011-01-20
4    http://espan.com      2010-10-01    2011-01-01
```

if Today is `2010-10-16`..

how can I get results work in today.

```
2    http://google.com     2010-10-15    2010-12-11
4    http://espan.com      2010-10-01    2011-01-01
```

Comment: data types of `start` and `end`?

Comment: 2010-10-17 is greater than 2010-10-10. The start date is supposed to be less than/equal to end date, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id, url, start, end
FROM Your_Table
WHERE 2010-10-16 BETWEEN start AND end
```

Replace `2010-10-16` with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or equivalent in MySQL

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE CURDATE() >= start AND CURDATE() <= end
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM that_table
WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN start AND end
```

Note that:

1. in the above example, both dates are "inclusive"
2. in the above example, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP includes the "time" part as well